# Don't call scroll event handler code on button click

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a list of buttons and divs associated with them. Each button is associated with each div. Right now when I click on a button it brings the div into viewport and the button gets activated (changes background color). And when I scroll, based on which div is inside the viewport, activated button changes.

The problem is when I click on a button randomly that is far from the previous button, it brings div into the scroll view but also you see the background color of all the intermediate buttons getting changed. I would like when the button is clicked, background of all the in-between buttons should NOT change.

I am not sure how can I achieve that.
Here's a codesandbox simulating the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-robinson-2dqrv?file=/src/App.js

For completion I am adding the code here as well.

```js
const { useEffect, useState, StrictMode } = React;

function App() {
  const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  const [currentItem, setCurrentItem] = useState(1);

  const handleBtnClk = (e) => {
    const id = parseInt(e.target.id, 10);
    setCurrentItem(id);
    document.querySelector(`[data-id="${id}"]`).scrollIntoView();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const scrollEvent = window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".item-div div");

      elements.forEach((element) => {
        var position = element.getBoundingClientRect();

        // checking whether fully visible
        if (position.top < window.innerHeight && position.bottom >= 0) {
          const previousElement = document.querySelector(".active");
          previousElement.classList.remove("active");

          const current = document.getElementById(element.dataset.id);
          current.classList.add("active");

          setCurrentItem(parseInt(element.dataset.id, 0));
        }
      });
    });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollEvent);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="item-btn">
        {items.map((item) => (
          <button
            key={item}
            id={item}
            onClick={(e) => handleBtnClk(e)}
            className={item === currentItem ? "active" : ""}
          >
            {item}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="item-div">
        {items.map((item) => (
          <div key={item} data-id={item}>{item}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```css
* {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.item-btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  top: 0px;
  position: sticky;
}

.item-btn button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid seagreen;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item-btn button:hover,
.item-btn button.active {
  background-color: seagreen;
}

.item-div div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
  <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
  <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
</body>

</html>
```